# Created 3 UITextField in UIAlertView but not getting action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have created an UIAlertView with three (3) UITextField. How i can get the action of UIAlertView. The clickedButtonAtIndex delegate method is working.

**But not getting the text i input in the field. Any idea ?** Thanks in advance.

```
UIView *v_alert = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 100)];
    v_alert.tag=10;

UITextField *textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,252,25)];
textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField1.placeholder = @"Your Previous Password";
textField1.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textField1.delegate = self;
textField1.tag=1;

[v_alert addSubview:textField1];

UITextField *textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,30,252,25)];
textField2.placeholder = @"Your New Password";
textField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField2.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textField2.delegate = self;
textField2.tag=2;

[v_alert addSubview:textField2];


UITextField *textField3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,60,252,25)];
textField3.placeholder = @"Email";
textField3.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField3.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textField3.delegate = self;
textField3.tag=3;

[v_alert addSubview:textField3];


alertV = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Change Password" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
[alertV setValue:v_alert  forKey:@"accessoryView"];
alertV.tag==100;
alertV.delegate=self;

[alertV show];
```

In delegate :

```
  - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
NSLog(@"didDismissWithButtonIndex");



       UITextField*txt1=[[[self.view viewWithTag:100] viewWithTag:10] viewWithTag:0];
     UITextField*txt2= [[[self.view viewWithTag:100] viewWithTag:10] viewWithTag:1];        
     UITextField*txt3= [[[self.view viewWithTag:100] viewWithTag:10] viewWithTag:2];

     NSLog(@"%@--%@--%@",txt1.text,txt2.text,txt3.text);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: alertV.delegate = self;

Comment: First of all alert view is deprecated from ios 8

Comment: @user3182143 is right, if you are working in or above iOS8 you have to use  `UIAlertController`

Comment: Yeah I agreed Kampai

Comment: @user3182143: set `delegate:self` will work for you

Comment: i was fighting with 3 field. @ Kampai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Declare Your 3 TextField**

```
UITextField *textField1, *textField2, *textField3;
```

**Then replace this code with your code.**

```
 UIView *alertview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
    alertview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    alertview.tag=10;
    textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,252,25)];
    textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField1.placeholder = @"Your Previous Password";
    textField1.secureTextEntry = YES;
    textField1.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textField1.delegate = self;
    textField1.tag=1;

    [alertview addSubview:textField1];

    textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,30,252,25)];
    textField2.placeholder = @"Your New Password";
    textField2.secureTextEntry = YES;
    textField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField2.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textField2.delegate = self;
    textField2.tag=2;

    [alertview addSubview:textField2];


    textField3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,60,252,25)];
    textField3.placeholder = @"Email";
    textField3.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField3.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textField3.delegate = self;
    textField3.tag=3;

    [alertview addSubview:textField3];


    UIAlertView *alertV = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Change Password" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
    [alertV setValue:alertview  forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    alertV.tag==100;
    alertV.delegate=self;

    [alertV show];
```

**Now your UIAlertView Button Method**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Button No click");
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
         NSLog(@"Button Yes Cancel");
    }
    NSLog(@"%@--%@--%@",textField1.text,textField2.text,textField3.text);
}
```

**Output :**
Gems--Moradiya--Himmoradiya@gmail.com

Comment: I have used three field!

Comment: then add one more field in [alert textFieldAtIndex:3].placeholder = @"Email ID"; after confirm password

Comment: Did you check you output ? Showing 2 field.

Comment: Ya you got email id that you enter in UialertView

Comment: i see two field only

Comment: @JamshedAlam did u create custom Alertview in your project ?

Comment: 3 field are added to uiview, the view is added to alertview as accessorview finally.

Comment: Are you getting output and text you input ?

Comment: No because ios 7 in UIAlertview did not support 3 field you can only use  UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput for input password .

Comment: Yes man! now you have come to point. I was fighting to to this. Thanks. You tried a lot.

Comment: @JamshedAlam now use this code your problem solve and give vote if this helpful too you and approve my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First set textField delegate

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then I tried the below code

```
    NSString *strAddress = @"14 UPPER CIRCULAR ROAD, Singapore 058412";

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:strAddress delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 100)];

    UITextField *textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,252,25)];
    textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField1.placeholder = @"Username";
    textField1.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textField1.delegate = self;
    [v addSubview:textField1];

    UITextField *textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,30,252,25)];
    textField2.placeholder = @"Password";
    textField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField2.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textField2.delegate = self;
    [v addSubview:textField2];


    UITextField *textField3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,60,252,25)];
    textField3.placeholder = @"Address";
    textField3.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField3.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textField3.delegate = self;
    [v addSubview:textField3];

    [alert setValue:v  forKey:@"accessoryView"];



    [alert show];
```

TextField Delegate method

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
    NSLog(@"The delegate method is called");
    return YES;
 }
```

Also see my screen shot

[image]

The output result is

```
  The delegate method is called
```

Comment: Delegate have set. I am not getting the text i typed.

Answer (score 0):

That's the trick i accepted. But the standard way is for latest iOS:

```
 UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"Change Password"
                              message:@""
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {

                          UITextField *alertText1 = [alert.textFields objectAtIndex:0];
                         UITextField *alertText2 = [alert.textFields objectAtIndex:1];
                         UITextField *alertText3 = [alert.textFields objectAtIndex:2];


                         if(alertText1.text.length>0&&alertText1.text.length>0)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"Resolving UIAlert Action for tapping OK Button:%@-%@-%@",alertText1.text,alertText2.text,alertText3.text);

                             oldpPass=alertText1.text;

                             NewPass=alertText2.text;

                            [self update_password];

                         }

                         [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"Resolving UIAlertActionController for tapping cancel button");
                             [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];

[alert addAction:ok];
[alert addAction:cancel];



[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter old password";
    textField.accessibilityIdentifier = @"paswordTextField";
    textField.accessibilityLabel = @"passwordLabel";
}];

[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter New password";
    textField.accessibilityIdentifier = @"paswordTextField";
    textField.accessibilityLabel = @"passwordLabel";
}];

[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * textField) {
    textField.accessibilityIdentifier = @"usernameTextField";
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter email";
    textField.text=self.emailTF.text;//
    textField.accessibilityLabel = @"usernameLabel";
}];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```